# Async Call to Snowflake from .Net

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to call a Snowflake Stored Procedure asynchronously from .Net? I am running a .Net Core API App using Snowflake’s DotNet driver. Basically I need to be able to use `conn.OpenAsync` and `cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync` like you normally would with a SQL Server, but that seems to be impossible.

```
executeResults.SessionId =RunNonQueryAsync(connectionString, command).Result;

static async Task<String> RunNonQueryAsync(string execConnection, string execCommand)
{
   String sessionId = null;
   using (IDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
   {
      conn.ConnectionString = execConnection;
      conn.Open();

      // Get Session Information
      IDbCommand cmd2 = conn.CreateCommand();
      cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT CURRENT_SESSION() as SESSION_ID";
      IDataReader rdr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
      while (rdr2.Read())
      {
         sessionId = rdr2.GetValue(0).ToString();
      }

      Task taskA = new Task(() =>
      {
         using (IDbConnection cn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
         {
            cn.ConnectionString = execConnection;
            cn.Open();
            IDbCommand cm = conn.CreateCommand();
            cm.CommandText = "call StoredProcedureThatTakes5MinutesToRun";

            cn.Close();
         }
      });
      taskA.Start();

    }
    return sessionId;
}
```

Comment: Everything can be made async with a little bit of work. Functions like `conn.OpenAsync()`? The function writers simply did that little bit of work for you.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more. I basically need to send an ExecuteNonQuery to the database but since the IDbConnection is SnowflakeDbConnection the Async call a just don’t work with Async await

Comment: You wrap the non-async function call, into a async function. There, you made it async. | The basic plumbing of async processing is well known. It basically is cooperative multitasking all over again (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking). Just this time, we have the compiler help with that plumbing code, so there is no room for programmer mistake.

Comment: I was trying that but it wasn’t working. Let me try again. I think one of the problems was that I was passing the connection and the command as parameters to the Async function. Also, I am running an API so I don’t need to do work after I call the ExecuteNonQuery, I just need it to start the job in the database and to send l/complete the HTTP pipeline with something like “process started successfully”.

Comment: "I was trying that but it wasn’t working." "Does not work" has never been a sufficient problem description.

Comment: Understood.I thought I had it but I still don't. And I don't think what I am trying to do is too crazy. Here are the actual details. My browser sends an HTTP GET which the DotNet API receives along with the properties [SQL Type: "NonQuery" AND StatementText:"Call StoredProcX"]. I am translating that to a simple cmd.ExecuteNonQuery. HOWEVER, what I need is to actually do two calls to the Database within the same session - 1 to get the Session ID, 2 to run the NonQuery in the background so I can then pass back a 202 resp"Process started - here is the session ID you can use to look up the status"

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 0):

> My browser sends an HTTP GET which the DotNet API receives along with the properties [SQL Type: "NonQuery" AND StatementText:"Call StoredProcX"].

That sounds like a absolute security nightmare. SQL Injections are bad enough, but that is basically putting a Central Venous Catheter into your Database.

At best, I would allow some simple Enumeration, integer or string value to be send with the request. One that is then passed through a switch/case statement. Maybe fed into a `Dictionary<String, Action>`, if that works better. The case or the action will then do the work of sending off the requests.

From there it is really just doing two things within then same connection:

```
     using (IDbConnection cn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
     {
        cn.Open();

        //Build command 1
        //Execute command 1
        //Do stuff with results of command 1

        //Build command 2
        //Execute command 2
        //Do stuff with results of command 2

        //Can propably be omited, as Dispose usually includes close. But we are talking about some 3rd party code, that might not be tested that well
        cn.Close();
     }
```